# PHP count the column without WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sum, calculated-columns

I am trying to calculate the column in PHP SQL without the `WHERE` clause. but the issue is, I am not able to do the SUM of a column by the GROUP.
I am trying to elaborate on the issue by showing the image below -

```
table name = production_tb

ID  |  qtycount  |  sku  | step_count | transaction
---------------------------------------------------
1   |  5         |  123  |  1         | 123456
2   |  5         |  123  |  1         | 123456
3   |  5         |  123  |  1         | 123456
4   |  8         |  123  |  2         | 123457
5   |  7         |  123  |  2         | 123457
6   |  3         |  123  |  3         | 123458
```

I tried this code `SELECT *, SUM(qtycount) FROM production_tb GROUP BY transaction` and I am getting 3 rows, I want to calculate that three rows in one and want the output will we be as `33`

I also use `DISTINCT` function but it is not working in repeating / duplicate numbers.

How I make this, I will use this function in the join table but I don't know the basics to do this so why I am asking this as a single table method. Please help me.

Comment: `SELECT (SELECT SUM(qtycount) FROM production_tb) as SUM_OF_ALL_QTY , * FROM production_tb `

Answer (score 0):

Could you give the output rows you expect? Because, if you want only one row, you could just do `SELECT SUM(qtycount) FROM production_tb`. Else, if you want the total of all with each group, you could do a sub select like:

```
SELECT 
  t1.*, 
  SUM(t1.qtycount), 
  (SELECT SUM(t2.qtycount) FROM production_tb as t2) AS total
FROM 
  production_tb as t1 
GROUP BY 
  t1.transaction
```

But a sub select will slow down the query with big result sets!

Comment: writing code is really simple but how I implement in this here `DISTINCT` function--
`https://jsfiddle.net/twt2shiv/mp5kwL4t/` `toatlConsumpQTY` and `totalReqQTY`

Comment: and your is still repeating 3 times